# How to upgrade PostgreSQL with PostGIS?

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, postgis, postgresql-9.3

I was running PostgreSQL 9.1 and I am trying to upgrade to PostgreSQL 9.3:

> $ /usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/pg_upgrade -b
>   /usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/bin -B /usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin -d
>   /var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main/ -D /var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main/ -O "-c
>   config_file=/etc/postgresql/9.3/main/postgresql.conf" -o "-c
>   config_file=/etc/postgresql/9.1/main/postgresql.conf"

However it fails with:

> Checking for presence of required libraries                 fatal
>
> Your installation references loadable libraries that are missing from
>   the new installation.  You can add these libraries to the new
>   installation, or remove the functions using them from the old
>   installation.  A list of problem libraries is in the file:
>       loadable_libraries.txt

`loadable_libraries.txt` contains:

> Could not load library "$libdir/postgis-1.5" ERROR:  could not access
>   file "$libdir/postgis-1.5": No such file or directory

It is similar to [Missing libraries when upgrading to PostGIS 2.1 and PostgreSQL 9.3.1 using homebrew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19597502/missing-libraries-when-upgrading-to-postgis-2-1-and-postgresql-9-3-1-using-homeb).

I am running Ubuntu and I have install PostgreSQL with PostGIS using `apt-get`.

Anyone managed that?

Comment: I'd try and find any directory named ```postgis-1.5``` and by its location, deduce where it should be copied in the new version. If that doesn't work, perhaps you should uninstall postgis1.5, upgrade and then add postgis 2.1 using ```CREATE EXTENSION```.

Comment: Can I uninstall postgis while having database that has geometry data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since [PostGIS 1.5 is not supported with PostgreSQL 9.3](https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiPostgreSQLPostGIS), you are also upgrading PostGIS versions. Since `pg_upgrade` cannot be used for this, you will need to follow the [hard upgrade procedure](http://www.postgis.org/docs/postgis_installation.html#hard_upgrade), which utilises logic in a `postgis_restore.pl` script that comes with PostGIS. If you have any further questions with the procedure, amend them to this question.