# Can I do a hard upgrade of a PostGIS-enabled database without the old PostGIS binaries?

Tags: postgresql, macos, homebrew, postgis

I want to upgrade a database that was created in Postgresql 10 & PostGIS 2.4 to Postgresql 11 & PostGIS 2.5. However, due to Homebrew constantly updating, I do *not* have the old Postgres/PostGIS database installed on my MacOS 10.14 system anymore.

As [asked in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19597502/2075003) and discussed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22889643/2075003) and also [my own](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/261559/23119), upgrading a PostGIS-enabled PostgreSQL database requires a [Hard Upgrade](http://www.postgis.org/docs/postgis_installation.html#hard_upgrade). In other words, dump the old database and restore it with a special PostGIS script.

However, I now find myself in a situation where I could install the old PostgreSQL 10 with `brew install postgresql@10`, but not PostGIS, because Homebrew has no more PostGIS 2.4 formula. Therefore, `pg_dump` will terminate with:

> [26040] ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/postgis-2.4": No such file or directory

Is there another way to upgrade an older PostGIS-enabled database?

**Update**

The `brew install postgis` installation is not recognizsed by the old postgres (`postgres@10`) version. Therefore, I cannot simply upgrade PostGIS, as suggested [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55576495/can-i-do-a-hard-upgrade-of-a-postgis-enabled-database-without-the-old-postgis-bi?noredirect=1#comment97852403_55576495).

```
ALTER EXTENSION postgis UPDATE
ERROR: could not open extension control file "/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@10/10.6_1/share/postgresql@10/extension/postgis.control": No such file or directory
```

Comment: Why not upgrade to 2.5 on the old system first (install PostGIS software and run `ALTER EXTENSION postgis UPDATE`) and then run `pg_upgrade`?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Hmm. Sounds reasonable. Will need to figure out how to run PostGIS with the `postgres@10` version. Right now it is not recognised. Any hints are very much welcome.

Comment: I thought you are already running it?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Sorry if that was unclear. Added an update. Only postgres is running not PostGIS

Comment: Now I am thoroughly confused. If you don't have PostGIS installed, then you don't have a "PostGIS-enabled database", right? Then you can just `pg_upgrade` and later install PostGIS.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Edited the question again. Hope it is clearer now. I was able to install the old Postgres but not the old PostGIS.

Comment: I see. There is always the option to install from source. Cumbersome with PostGIS, but possible.

Answer (score -1):

I ended up using an [older version](https://postgresapp.com/downloads.html) of the [Postgress.app](https://postgresapp.com/),  which offers the option to use PostgreSQL 10.7 & PostGIS 2.4.6. From there I can use the older binaries in `/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/10/bin`.